# Stored Procedure Result Set vs. Return Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm not even sure I can describe this adequately, but start with this:  I've got a stored procedure that handles getting a lot of data and for concurrently, I've set it to do the following:

- Get the highest batch # as a variable
- update all unprocessed records with that batch #
- select all those records
- mark them as processed

(Code will be shown below)

This stored procedure is being executed by GoAnywhere, a data transfer tool. GoAnywhere is executing the query fine, and is even showing that it's retrieving the right set of records, but is bombing out at the point where it should be using the result set from the select statement to update the destination database. The error it's getting is that it can't convert an integer into a rowset.

I've figured out that, in SQL Server, a stored procedure always returns a 1 or a 0 as a return value, in addition to the result set. For some reason, GoAnywhere seems to be picking that up instead of the result of the SQL statement.

I've determined that if I comment out the lines of code commented out in the code sample below, GoAnywhere picks up the result set and handles it nicely.

My question: is there a way to modify this stored procedure so that the default return value will be the result set instead of the 1 or zero, short of breaking this up into multiple stored procedure calls?

Alternative question: if I get really lucky and there are GoAnywhere experts viewing this, I'd be just as happy with how to get GoAnywhere to ignore the return value and accept the result set as-is.

Stored procedure code:

```
USE [myDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[myProcedure]    Script Date: 10/31/2014 13:42:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE myProcedure
AS
    DECLARE @BatchId int;
    DECLARE @BatchDate datetime;

    SET @BatchId = (select IsNull(Max(ProcessBatchID), 0) + 1 FROM myTable)
    set @BatchDate = GetDate();

    -- UPDATE myTable SET ProcessBatchID = @BatchId, ProcessedDateTime = @BatchDate, ProcessingStatus = 'Processing' WHERE ProcessBatchID IS NULL;

    SELECT  
       FullCardNumber, CustomerMarsNumber, CustomerLevelId, 
       CustomerLevelName, ProcessBatchID 
    FROM   
       myTable 
    WHERE    
       ProcessBatchID = @BatchId;

    -- UPDATE myTable SET ProcessingStatus = 'Processed' WHERE ProcessBatchID = @BatchId;
```

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the top of your procedure.

Comment: @Cory - thank you!  I wish you'd posted as an answer so I could vote it up and accept it, since you were the first to post the right solution.  But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know GoAnywhere, and this is a long shot, but try adding

```
SET NOCOUNT on
```

to your procedure, immediately after the `AS` statement. SQL will return a rowcount for every query run, and that returned information may be confusing the application.  (I've never been that clear on just how that information is returned...)

Guessing a number and ignoring the dataset returned by the `SELECT` statement, the output from a call to your procedure might look like:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

(By the by, a call to a SQL stored procedure returns an integer value as defined by the `RETURN` statement, with the default value being 0. Just how this returned value is caught and used depends on the application.)